# Setting Tesseract options in R version

Tags: r, tesseract

Does anyone know how to change Tesseract options in R? According to the manual you should be able to supply a list of keywords and values. If trying to set the option ‘preserve_interword_spaces=1’. Doesn’t stick though.
After setting the parameter and running ‘tesseract_params()’ preserve_interword_spaces is still set to 0, the default value.

Comment: I haven't used it, but does https://stackoverflow.com/a/58193849 help?  Looks like the options are passed as a list - `options = list(preserve_interword_spaces = 1)`, not as a string

Comment: Doesn't work in the current version but thanks for the suggestion. The suggested command 'tesseract::ocr(tesseract(options = list(preserve_interword_spaces = 1)))' throws an error. (tesseract(options = list(preserve_interword_spaces = 1))) is accepted but doesn't change the actual parameter